# Using a userform in a non Excel VB script

Tags: vbscript

I am working on a windows project using VB Script (I am currently writing it in notepad). It is a file selector and I want the user to select a file and the script to remember the file selected. The way I found how to do this is to use a userform. The only tutorials that I found are done in an Excel environment and didn't seem applicable to a non-Excel script. Is there a way for me to use a userform in my program? If not, I just want a dropdown message box that allows a user to select a row and for the script to remember the selection.

Comment: What do mean by `non Excel VBA script`? Does it mean you do not want to use `user form`?

Comment: I am writing a script in notepad that runs in windows, not Excel. I am not writing it in Excel or for Excel, it is a stand-alone application.

Comment: So, why the question is tagged as `excel`?

Comment: VBA must run within an application, whether a Microsoft Office application or some other that supports VBA (= Visual Basic for *Applications*). You can't run VBA from NotePad and you can't work with VBA UserForms there, either.

Comment: I have written VBA programs in notepad before (Mainly 'shell.sendkeys') I don't know what runs those programs, they just run. What do you mean I can't run VBA from NotePad?

Comment: You can use VBScript ([Visual Basic Scripting Edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript)) from Notepad, but not VBA ([Visual Basic for Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications)).  Try looking at [this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_fileopen.php)?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying knowing that it is called VBScript will help we google better.